# Why won't PHP set my cookie (No errors)

Tags: php, cookies

This is the very simple code I am using to set a cookie in PHP:

```
setcookie("vgc_email", $userinfo['email']) or emsg("Unable to set cookie");
```

Error_reporting is set to E_ALL and is not giving an error, however, `Unable to set cookie` is given when I attempt to run this code, and no cookie is set. I have made sure that `$userinfo['email']` is not empty. I am also sure that I am able to receive cookies, when using Facebook connect is has set a cookie on the website.
So why won't this one work?

Comment: The answer is in the [manual on `setcookie()`.](http://php.net/setcookie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual:](http://php.net/setcookie)

> If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail
>   and return FALSE. If setcookie() successfully runs, it will return
>   TRUE. This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie.

so most likely, you are outputting data before calling `setcookie()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the headers were sent before setting a cookie with `headers_sent()`